# wxpython grid: Hovering with mouse over other cells while editing resets the editing

Tags: grid, wxpython, editor, onmouseover

I'm using wxpython (version 4.1.0 on Windows 10) grid to create a GUI and stumbled over this annoying bug:
If I select a cell and start the editing and in parallel hover with the mouse over other cells (without left-clicking), the editing will reset to an empty string continuously. It doesn't permanently lose focus, so if I continue writing, it will still edit the same cell. Here is a basic grid example to replicate this behavior:

```
"""Contains the main window of the Test view as well as the main function for the Test client."""
import wx
import wx.adv
import wx.grid as grid
from overrides import overrides


class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    """The test frame."""

    def __init__(self, parent: wx.Window, title: str) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent, title=title, size=(1200, 600))
        self.panel = TestPanel(self)


class TestPanel(wx.Panel):
    """The main panel of the Test window, containing all graphical elements."""

    def __init__(self, parent: wx.Window) -> None:
        super(TestPanel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.grid = grid.Grid(self)
        self.grid.CreateGrid(2, 11)
        self.top_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.top_sizer.Add(self.grid, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.top_sizer)
        self.bottom_row_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.top_sizer.Add(self.bottom_row_sizer, 0, wx.EXPAND)


class TestApp(wx.App):
    """The Test app object."""

    @overrides
    def OnInit(self) -> bool:
        """Initializes the window."""
        TestFrame(parent=None, title="Test").Show()
        return True


def main() -> None:
    """Main control-flow entry function."""
    TestApp().MainLoop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I'll probably have to override the `BeginEdit` or `ApplyEdit` method of the default `wx.grid.GridCellEditor` class, but I'm struggling with the actual solution.

Comment: Works fine under Linux wx 4.1.0. I don't know what `overrides` is but I doubt it's the issue. I'd try a diffrent mouse to start with, in case it's faulty.

Comment: You should add information about wxPython version and operating system. I couldn't reproduce it with wx 4.0.6 on Win 7.

Comment: Thanks for you answers: The mouse doesn't seem to be the issue... It's Windows 10 and wxpython version 4.1.0.